# Is there a callback interface in android.view.View which indicate that the view itself turned unseen?

Tags: background, callback, android-view

`View.onDetachedFromWindow` means the view no longer has a surface for drawing, `View.onWindowFocusChanged` means the window containing this view gains or loses focus.

I need a callback that means the View turns unseen. There are more than one case of turning unseen, maybe visibility of view changed or view go to background.
there a callback like this? Who can give me some advice?

Comment: use `ViewTreeObserver`

Comment: Sadly I think the only reliable way to go is to extend View which visibility changes you want to track and override `onVisibilityChanged` method.

Answer (score 0):

This `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` seems to be what you are looking for.

As it says [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html):

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.